# how to incrementing cell? - python - openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, openpyxl

### Python - Openpyxl - Incrementing Cell

I already try 4 type of code for this, like:
I already look for some various kind of this problem, but I still can't get through it

```
cc2 = 2
cc2i = 2
while cc2 < 5000:
    while cc2i < 5000:
        ws['c{}'.format(int(cc2))] = ArrayFormula("c{}:c{}".format(int(cc2), 5000), "=upper(Input!f{}".format(int(cc2i))+")")
        cc2 += 5
        cc2i += 1`

#or

cc2 = 2
cc2i = 2
while cc2 < 5000:
    while cc2i < 5000:
        ws['c{}'.format(str(cc2))] = ArrayFormula("c{}:c{}".format(str(cc2), 5000), "=upper(Input!f{}".format(str(cc2i))+")")
        cc2 += 5
        cc2i += 1

#or

for cc2 in range(2, 5000, 5):
    for cc2i in range(2, 5000, 1)
        ws['c{}'.format(int(cc2))] = ArrayFormula("c{}:c{}".format(int(cc2), 5000), "=upper(Input!f{}".format(int(cc2i))+")")

#or

for cc2 in range(2, 5000, 5):
    for cc2i in range(2, 5000, 1)
        ws['c{}'.format(str(cc2))] = ArrayFormula("c{}:c{}".format(str(cc2), 5000), "=upper(Input!f{}".format(str(cc2i))+")")
```

what I expect to get are

```
ws['c2'] = '=input!f2'
ws['c7'] = '=input!f3'
ws['c12'] = '=input!f4'
```

and so on

but what i get are

```
ws['c2'] = '=input!f2'
ws['c3'] = '=input!f2'
ws['c4'] = '=input!f2'
```

and so on

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do and the results don't match the code. Looping with steps is easy enough in Python, you must be doing something else.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you want is the code sample below;
In the loop;

1. cc2 is incremented by 5 up to 5000. Starting from 2
2. cc2i is incremented by 1 for each cc2 increment. Starting from 1

Therefore cc2 is used in the cell coordinate;

```
ws[f'c{cc2}']
```

and will refer to cells

> ws[c2],ws[c7],ws[c12],ws[c17],ws[c22],ws[c27],ws[c32],ws[c37],ws[c42],ws[c47],ws[c52]
> ...

The corresponding formula referencing the F cell will increases by 1. Not sure exactly what your formula is supposed to include since your code states one thing and your expected and actual ouput indicates another.
Whatever the make up of the formula, the F cell references will be;

> F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11...

example code

```
for cc2i, cc2 in enumerate(range(2, 5000, 5),1):
    ws[f'c{cc2}'] = f'=UPPER(Input!F{cc2i})'
```

Comment: what about multiple cc2i? is that possible? because I try multiple range, multiple for loop and multiple enumerate isn't possible

Comment: In the example cc2i is the index of the loop, it moves for each position from 1st to last element in the given range. Usually the 1st element is position 0 so the value of cc2i would be 0, the next element is position 1 so cc2i changes to value 1 etc. However as you have seen in the example, the enumerate start can be set to any integer value, in this case set to 1 so its value was 1 for the 1st element and 2 for the 2nd and so on. Either way will increment from the start number by 1 to the last element in the loop. Therefore in the loop there are only these two values; index and element.

Comment: If you required another counter in the loop you may be able to make use of either or both of these counters if that counter increment is linear to either one of these counters For example if you needed a counter that incremented by 10 on each loop that could be achieved as **cc2i * 10** (with enumerate start at 1).

Comment: Another option is to use `zip`. This allows you to loop through 2 or more iterable objects together. e.g. if you have three ranges `zip` will allow you to loop all three together to obtain each element per loop and also include the index with enumerate. Note that zip will truncate the loop at the lowest range. Example `for count, (val1, val2, val3) in enumerate(zip(range(4), range(2, 5000, 5), range(2, 100, 4)))` Loops the three ranges and assigns each element to the variables `val1`, `val2`, and `val3` Note they are contained in brackets. The index is included as the variable `count`.

Comment: For the example code line you would get 4 interations with 4 values, the index, val1, val2, & val3 like this:- **1st loop** output will be: `0, 0, 2, 2` , **2nd loop** output will be `1, 1, 7, 6` etc. The loop will be restricted to just 4 iterations because the first range `range(4)` contains only 4 elements.

Comment: 'cc2i * 10' really useful, it works fine with it, but on 'zip' I should learn it more, I still don't get it